# Dismiss with Prejudice Following Settlement - Do I lose protection for a new claim?

Tags: small-claims-court

I went to small claims and received a default judgment in my favor (I was the plaintiff).  I got my money, now the question is do we then file a motion to dismiss (with prejudice)?  If we do that, will I be prevented from filing a claim if a NEW claim occurs?  Will this be treated as an entirely new claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be tautological but the release releases whatever the release releases.

If it is limited to the particular event (as it should be) you can claim for other events. If it is a blanket indemnity then you can't.